# Is $E[X\vert Y,Z]$ necessarily a function of $Y,Z$ only? $X,Y,Z$ are random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

I am wondering whether $E[X\vert Y,Z]$ is a function of $Y,Z$ only? (That is, given that we don't know anything about $X$ besides that it is a R.V).

I am thinking yes, and my logic is that if $X$ is some function (a random variable), then it is a function of $Y,Z$ and possible other stuff. Once I condition on $Y,Z$ and take the expectation, though, anything that is not $Y,Z$ (the "possible other stuff") does not matter anymore, because we take the expected value (which is a constant).

That is, we integrate over all possible values of whatever is not $Y,Z$, and therefore all terms besides $Y,Z$ go away when we take $E[X\vert Y,Z]$

My motivation for the question is that if, for example $X= 2Y + Z +W^2$ where $W$ is also an R.V, then 
$$E[X\vert Y,Z] =E[2Y+Z+W^2\vert Y,Z] = 2Y + Z +E[W^2\vert Y,Z]$$
and I think $E[W^2\vert Y,Z]$ is just a constant after we compute the expectation (sum or integrate).

What makes me second guess that the answer is "yes" is that I am unsure whether the bounds of the integral 
$$E[W^2\vert Y,Z]=\int_a^b w^2 f_{W\vert \{Y,Z\}} dw$$
can maybe depend on some variable besides $Y,Z$ values.

Thanks.

Comment: What about fetching a *definition* of conditional expectation in its full measure theoretic sense, say on WP, and check that the answer is "Obviously yes, by definition" (and that it certainly does not require conditional densities, which is as well since these may not exist)?

Comment: In part this Question seems to be born from using a shorthand notation that confuses the meaning of conditional expectation.  A more elaborate expression $E(X|Y=y,Z=z)$ shows clearly that the value of random variable $X$ is conditioned by specific values $y,z$, and it is these (ordinary) variables who values determine the conditional expectation of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, of course. Recall the definition of conditional expectation:

> **Definition**: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space, $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ a random variable and $\mathcal A\subset \mathcal F$ a $\sigma$-algebra. We define the *conditional expectation* $Y=\mathbb E[X \mid \mathcal A]$ as the only random variable satisfying
>
> 1. $Y$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable.
> 2. For every $A\in \mathcal A$,
>    $$\mathbb E[X1_A ]=\mathbb E[Y1_A]$$

Existence and uniqueness in the $\mathcal L^2_+$ case are a consequence of the existence of orthogonal projections, while the general case is obtained by approximation.

The other crucial part to show what you are saying is the following theorem:

> **Theorem**: Let $(E, \mathcal E)$ be a measurable space, $X: \Omega \to E$ a function. Endow $\Omega$ with the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(X)=X^\leftarrow(\mathcal E)$. Let $Y:(\Omega, \sigma(X)) \to (\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ be a measurable function.
> Then there exists a measurable function $f:(E, \mathcal E)\to(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ such that
> $$Y=f \circ X$$

To prove your claim for one random variable, just observe that if you set $\mathcal A=\sigma (Y)$, then $\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal A]$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable by definition. As a consequence of the theorem there exists a function $f$ such that
$$\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal A]=\mathbb E[X\mid Y]=f \circ Y$$
so the conditional expectation depends solely on $Y$.